# Solaris10のファイル名の文字化け

Tags: shellscript, solaris

初めて質問します。

Soalris10環境で日本語ディレクトリ名作成を作成すると文字化けします。 
 同様な現象や回避方法を知っている方いますでしょうか。 
 最終的には、日本語ファイル名を使わないようにする予定ですが、既存のものを一時的に何とかしたいと考えています。

文字化けする環境と再現手順は、以下の通りです。

```
$ uname -a
SunOS osc20068 5.10 Generic_147440-27 sun4v sparc sun4v
$ cat /etc/release
                   Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10s_u10wos_17b SPARC
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 23 August 2011
$ echo $LANG
ja_JP.UTF-8 
$

$ mkdir 品 目 品目
$ ls
品     目     哇���
$
```

取得した16進ダンプの写しを添付します。

```
$ mkdir a品a b目b c品目c
$ ls
a品a b目b c哇���c
$ ls -d a*
a品a
$ ls -d a* | od -cx
0000000 a 345 223 201 a \n
         61e5   9381   610a
0000006
$ ls -d b*
b目b
$ ls -d b* | od -cx
0000000 b 347 233 256 b \n
         62e7   9bae   620a
0000006
$ ls -d c*
c哇���c
$ ls -d c* | od -cx
0000000 c 345 223 207 222 233 256 c \n
         63e5   9387   929b   ae63   0a00
0000011
```

追加で取得したダンプです。

```
$ ls
a品a     b目b     c哇���c
$ LANG=C ls | od -tx1
0000000 61 e5 93 81 61 0a 62 e7 9b ae 62 0a 63 e5 93 87
0000020 92 9b ae 63 0a
0000025
$
```

historyやlsの結果をファイルに保管、表示した場合は文字化けしませんでした。

```
$ ls
a品a     b目b     c哇���c
$ echo a品a b目b c品目c >tmp.txt; cat tmp.txt
a品a b目b c品目c
$ history | grep mkdir
  503  mkdir a品a b目b c品目c
  510  history | grep mkdir
$
```

ファイルでも同様に文字化けしました。

```
$ touch 品 目 品目
$ ls
品     目     哇���
$
```

文字化けした結果をファイルに保管したものは、文字化けします。
ファイルシステムの問題かもしれません。

```
$ ls
品     目     哇���
$ ls > tmp.txt
$ cat tmp.txt
tmp.txt
品
目
哇���
$
```

Comment: `LANG=C ls | od -tx1`とするとどうなりますか？Solarisが手元にないのでodのオプションが間違っているかもしれませんが、16進数のダンプを取りたいのです。

Comment: Kenjiさん

アドバイスありがとうございます。
日中に取得した16進ダンプの写しを添付します。
明日LANGを指定したダンプを取ってみます。

`
$ mkdir a品a b目b c品目c
$ ls
a品a     b目b     c哇���c
$
 
$ ls -d a*
a品a
$ ls -d a* | od -cx
0000000   a 345 223 201   a  \n
            61e5    9381    610a
0000006
$
 
$ ls -d b*
b目b
$ ls -d b* | od -cx
0000000   b 347 233 256   b  \n
            62e7    9bae    620a
0000006
$

 
$ ls -d c*
c哇���c
$ ls -d c* | od -cx
0000000   c 345 223 207 222 233 256   c  \n
            63e5    9387    929b    ae63    0a00
0000011
$
`

Comment: echo a品a b目b c品目c >tmp.txt; cat tmp.txt ですとか、historyで表示されるコマンド履歴とかは大丈夫で、あくまでファイル名のみの問題なのでしょうか。

Comment: コメントいただいた内容で確認してみました。
質問文に追加する形で結果を添付しました。
echoやhisotryでは、文字化けはしませんでした。

Comment: 「品目」を表すUTF-8バイト列「e5 93 81 e7 9b ae」が、どこかで「e5 93 87 92 9b ae」に変換されてしまっていますね。「81 e7」と「87 92」は、ともにSJISで「∫」を表す文字ですので、「ファイルシステムがファイル名をSJISとして解釈して正規化した」状態になっているようです。端末側、Solaris(shell)側の文字コード設定をSJISにしてどうなるか試してみてください。

Comment: ファイル作成時にすでに失敗しているようですね。それも特定の文字だけ失敗しているような気がします。`locale`の出力を載せてください。そもそも`ja_JP.UTF-8 `がシステムにインストールされているのでしょうか？

Comment: Solaris 10のファイルシステムはUFSだと思うので、ファイルシステムがファイル名をSJISとして解釈することはないでしょう。8bitクリーンで、エンコーディングも何も強制されません。品目というファイルがない状態で`perl -e 'open HANDLE, (">\xe5\x93\x81\xe7\x9b\xae")'`を実行してLANG=ja_JP.UTF-8で`ls`するとどうなりますか？UTF-8で`品目`という空のファイルが作成されるでしょうか？

Comment: perlで作成した日本語フィアル名でも同じように文字化けしました。

$ ls
$ perl -e 'open HANDLE, (">\xe5\x93\x81\xe7\x9b\xae")'
$ echo $LANG
ja_JP.UTF-8
$ ls
哇���
$

Comment: 順序がバラバラですみません。

localeの出力です。

$ locale
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$

Comment: インストールされているlocaleにja_JP.UTF-8は含まれていました。

# localeadm -lc
インストール済みのパッケージを検査しています。しばらくお待ちください。
...省略...
完了。
このレポートのコピーは /var/sadm/system/data/locales.list 内に格納されています
# less /var/sadm/system/data/locales.list
2016年04月05日 (火) 09時36分47秒 JST の osc20068 上にインストールされている地域は、次のとおりです

POSIX (C)

日本語 (ja)
[ ja, ja_JP.eucJP, ja_JP.PCK, ja_JP.UTF-8 ]

#

Comment: Le Pere d'OOさん

LANGをSJISに指定して実行してみましたが、改善しませんでした。

$ env | grep LC
$ echo $LANG
ja_JP.PCK
$ ls
$ mkdir 品目
$ ls
哇���
$

Comment: `/etc/default/init` の `LANG` の値も `ja_JP.UTF-8` ですか？

Comment: 再現できる環境がないので当てずっぽうですが `setterm -x UTF-8` で端末の設定を変えてみるとどうでしょうか。

Comment: あと[ユーザーズガイド](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0364/japan.utility-3/index.html)によると`stty deteucw`とすると setterm を使わずにすむらしいので試してみてはどうでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

まずは、`$LANG` が環境変数になっている (シェルで `export` されている) こと、`$LC_ALL` が設定されていないか、値に見えない文字が含まれていないかの確認をしてください。

```
$ env |egrep '^(LANG|LC_ALL)='
$ printf '%s' "$LANG" |cat -v
$ printf '%s' "$LC_ALL" |cat -v
```

ファイルシステムの問題かもしれないので、マウント元やマウントオプションを確認してください。

```
$ nawk -v m="`df . |sed 's/ .*//'`" '$3==m {print}' /etc/vfstab
$ mount |grep "^`df . |sed 's/ .*//'` "
```

とりあえず、ここまで。原因や、ここまでの操作で得られる情報で何かわかるかは現時点では不明。

Answer (score 0):

原因は見当も付きませんが、例えばShiftJISの`5c`問題のように特定のバイトが原因になっている可能性があるならば、ファイル名を「品目」から1バイトずつ変えていき、どのバイトを変えると文字化けがなくなるか観察するという手もありますね。

例:

```
# utf-8 で 1byte のみ違う文字列
擁目      b'\xe6\x93\x81\xe7\x9b\xae'
唁目      b'\xe5\x94\x81\xe7\x9b\xae'
哂目      b'\xe5\x93\x82\xe7\x9b\xae'
品蛮      b'\xe5\x93\x81\xe8\x9b\xae'
品眮      b'\xe5\x93\x81\xe7\x9c\xae'
品盯      b'\xe5\x93\x81\xe7\x9b\xaf'
# sjis で 1byte のみ違う文字列
吠目      b'\x96i\x96\xda'
彬目      b'\x95j\x96\xda'
品瑠      b'\x95i\x97\xda'
品杢      b'\x95i\x96\xdb'
# euc-jp で 1byte のみ違う文字列
癖目      b'\xca\xca\xcc\xdc'
彬目      b'\xc9\xcb\xcc\xdc'
品養      b'\xc9\xca\xcd\xdc'
品杢      b'\xc9\xca\xcc\xdd'
# iso-2022-jp で 1byte のみ違う文字列
癖目      b'\x1b$BJJL\\\x1b(B'
彬目      b'\x1b$BIKL\\\x1b(B'
品養      b'\x1b$BIJM\\\x1b(B'
品杢      b'\x1b$BIJL]\x1b(B'
```

例の出力に使用したスクリプト:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
orig = "品目"
for enc in "utf-8", "sjis", "euc-jp", "iso-2022-jp":
    print("#", enc, "で 1byte のみ違う文字列")
    new_byte_list = list(bytes(orig, enc))
    for i in range(len(new_byte_list)):
        if enc == "iso-2022-jp" and (i < 3 or i > len(new_byte_list) - 4):
            continue
        new_byte_list[i] += 1
        b = bytes(new_byte_list)
        print(str(b, enc), "    ", b)
        new_byte_list[i] -= 1
```